# Using 'Agg' during nosetests

Tags: unit-testing, matplotlib, nose

I have a unit test which tests a function that creates a few plots.  I don't want figures to be created for those plots so I added `matlplotlib.use('Agg')` to both the **unit test** and the **function**.

These are the **First** two lines of both the unit test and the function:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
```

...and I still get this message:

```
This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect
because the backend has already been chosen;
matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.
```

...when I run:

```
nosetests my_unit_test.py
```

Does nosetests run other code in the directory prior to running my unit test?

Comment: I think the backend is set to a default value on import which you could change the default backend in the `.matplotlibrc` file (http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html). Adding this in the directory of the unit test may work.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  I originally tried this and it didn't work but I came back to it and realized I messed it up if you add this as the response I will accept it as the answer.  All I needed was a file named `matplotlibrc` to exist in the folder with nothing but `backend      :  agg` in the file

Comment: Hi @Chris, thanks for getting back, I've added an answer below, please let me know if it needs more details in order to allow nosetests to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Chris I'm adding the comment above as an answer in case anyone else has the same problem. It seem the solution is to change the default backend in the `.matplotlibrc` file (see matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html). As the backend is set to a default value on import, specifying the correct backend in the `.matplotlibrc` stored in the directory of the unit test appears to solve the problem. Note that the system checks the local folder first and then defaults to the system `.matplotlibrc` if not found locally. In this way, a custom defaults file can be included with the unit tests.